# Exact SQL query returns different data using MySQL Command Line and PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query that returns the last 10 news and last 10 comments to each of them from the database.

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE news (
  news_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  article TEXT NOT NULL,
  type_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  news_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (news_id)
);

CREATE TABLE comments (
  comment_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  message TEXT NOT NULL,
  news_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  msg_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (comment_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_comments_news_id FOREIGN KEY (news_id)
    REFERENCES news (news_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

SELECT news_id, comment_id, rnk
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    @rnk:=IF(@prev_news_id=news_id, @rnk+1, 1) rnk,
    @prev_news_id:=news_id
  FROM (
    SELECT
      lastnews.*,
      cmts.comment_id,
      cmts.message,
      cmts.msg_time
    FROM (SELECT * FROM news WHERE type_id=5 ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 10) lastnews
      LEFT OUTER JOIN comments cmts ON cmts.news_id=lastnews.news_id
    ORDER BY cmts.news_id DESC, cmts.comment_id DESC) t1) t2
WHERE rnk <= 10;
```

PHP:

```
$query = <<<_END
SELECT news_id, comment_id, rnk
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    @rnk:=IF(@prev_news_id=news_id, @rnk+1, 1) rnk,
    @prev_news_id:=news_id
  FROM (
    SELECT
      lastnews.*,
      cmts.comment_id,
      cmts.message,
      cmts.msg_time
    FROM (SELECT * FROM news WHERE type_id=5 ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 10) lastnews
      LEFT OUTER JOIN comments cmts ON cmts.news_id=lastnews.news_id
    ORDER BY cmts.news_id DESC, cmts.comment_id DESC) t1) t2
WHERE rnk <= 10;
_END;

$db = new PDO('mysql:='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$dbh = $db->prepare($query);
$dbh->execute();
$data = $dbh->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
print_r($data);
```

The query works perfectly in MySQL cmd, but returns wrong data in PHP. The problem is in **rnk** row. It always equals 1. Why is that?

**UPDATE:** I just restarted MySQL Command Line and it broke even there. But then I turned on profiling with `SET profiling=1` and suddenly it works again. What is more, turning off profiling doesn't negate the effect.

Comment: Dumb question, but are you sure you are looking at the array's value and not its index?

Comment: I'm 100% sure. It returns all comments with rnk=1. It doesn't matter what I set in `WHERE rnk <= 10`;

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was with user-defined variables initialization. We should do it explicitly to avoid undefined behavior.
In our case we add one more join:

```
FROM (SELECT * FROM news WHERE type_id=5 ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 10) lastnews
  LEFT OUTER JOIN comments cmts ON cmts.news_id=lastnews.news_id
  INNER JOIN (SELECT @rnk:=0,@prev_news_id:=0) t3
```